# how do i get the frame to fill the screen om tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

im creating a quiz for my computer science project and i am unable to get the customtkinter background to fill the whole screen

here is a screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5SV5.png)

and here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
import customtkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class homepage(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
      def __init__(self, master):
          customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, master)
          self.Frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(
          master=self,).pack()

          self.Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="sign up", 
                        command=lambda: master.switch_frame( "pagethree")).pack()
        
          self.Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="login", 
          command=lambda: master.switch_frame(            "Pageone")).pack()
```

Comment: What creates `homepage`? Also please look at the PEP8 variable naming convention

Comment: i have got a main.py that work fine however when i open this window the frame doesn't filll the screen

Comment: Whatever calls `.pack()`/`.grid()` on the `homepage` object, needs to force the frame to expand. Please update your question with a [mre].

Comment: It doesn't look like you're even trying to make it fill the window. `pack` has several options, you aren't using any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to put inside pack(): fill and expand options? Here is the change.

```
from tkinter import*
import customtkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class homepage(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
      def __init__(self, master):
          customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, master)
          self.Frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(
          master=self,).pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)

          self.Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="sign up", 
                        command=lambda: master.switch_frame( "pagethree")).pack()
        
          self.Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="login", 
          command=lambda: master.switch_frame(            "Pageone")).pack()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).